# Read value of an html script element in Angular, which is of type json

Tags: javascript, django, angular, getelementbyid

In the html page, there will be a script element which is a static content ( generated from a Django backend) with an ID.

```
<script id="hello-data" type="application/json">{"hello": "world\\u003C/script\\u003E\\u0026amp;"}</script>
```

I wanted to get that data in an angular service ( or even component) which would have a simple getElementById is javascript.

```
const value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);
```

I did a lot of searches, found answers pointing to "ViewChild", "@Inject(DOCUMENT)", but none of these works on a 'script' tag.

Any pointers to solution would be really appreciated :)

Edits: Below is what I have tried with DOCUMENT

```
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document) {
    let el = document.getElementById('hello-data'); 
    console.log(el); // This prints null
    //this.data = JSON.parse(el.textContent);

  }
```

Interestingly, if I tired to access any other element by ID, it works. I see the issue only with script tag.

Comment: To understand this correctly. You have an angular app and get a response from a Django Backend. right?

Comment: You can access elements in the DOM via `document` in Angular. You can use the `DOCUMENT` abstraction provided by Angular, or if you're not running Angular Universal, you can just use `document` as you would in any other script, even if it's in a service

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with what you have? I'm getting a valid object?

Comment: I tired with ehe `DOCUMENT` abstraction , but it's not working.
I think it's because I am trying to access the script element with id, where the script is NOT javascript. From the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type) , it won't be rendered and probably that's the reason its not picking up?

Comment: The type of the script tag is irrelevant. A tag is a tag is a tag. If it has an ID, you can select it.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [IANA Media Types registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text), [RFC 9239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239.html), and the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages:text/javascript), JavaScript content should always be served using the MIME type text/javascript. No other MIME types are considered valid for JavaScript, and using any MIME type other than text/javascript may result in scripts that do not load or run.

-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#javascript_types